# Can I get a tax deduction for education expenses?

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction, education

I work as a Computer Programmer for a Healthcare Company. I am in the process of applying for Part Time - Master's Graduation Program in Healthcare.

I wonder whether i would be able to get Tax Deduction for the expenses incurred in Master's Graduation.

I live and work in NJ, Most likely, I would be admitted for the program in NYC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably.  There are quite a few tax benefits for education expenses that you might qualify for.  The IRS has a description of the various options on a page called [Tax Benefits for Education](https://www.irs.gov/newsroom/tax-benefits-for-education-information-center).

The big three programs are the American Opportunity Tax Credit, the Lifetime Learning Credit, or the Tuition and Fees Deduction.  For each educational expense you have, you can only claim one type of benefit.  So if you qualify for more than one, you need to figure out which is the most beneficial to choose.  The IRS has a [comparison of these three benefits](http://www.eitc.irs.gov/Other-Refundable-Credits/educompchart).

There are others that may or may not apply to you, all explained on the IRS's Tax Benefits for Education site.  If you have any more specific questions about a particular tax benefit, feel free to ask a new question.